# How to find the second highest grade point average In SQL Query

Tags: sql

My Data Base is an SQL server And My Query Is Below

```
SELECT name, MAX(average) AS average
FROM Course
WHERE salary <> (SELECT MAX(salary) 
FROM Course);
```

I Want Get Second Highest Average in Class

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Where is the "grade" in your example? Do you want the name with the second highest _salary_ or second highest _average_? If you want the second highest average, then why do you compare the salary in the WHERE clause?

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (not images.) [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT name, average AS average
FROM Course
WHERE average = (SELECT Top(2) MAX(salary) 
FROM Course)
```

Answer (score 1):

No dbms specified but for MySQL and PostgreSQL You can use the limit and offset to get the second highest grade. Remove the `MAX` aggregation on the `average` column.

```
SELECT name, average AS average
FROM Course
WHERE salary <> (SELECT MAX(salary) 
FROM Course)
ORDER BY average DESC
LIMIT 1,2;
```

In MSSQL > 2012 you can use OFFSET and FETCH

```
OFFSET 1 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

Comment: Product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least tell us which product this is for.